# Looking for location of a quote, "Nothing can work damage to me except myself", attributed to Ralph Waldo Emerson

Tags: quote-source, ralph-waldo-emerson

In what piece of work by Ralph Waldo Emerson can one find the following quote?

> Nothing can work damage to me except myself; the damage that I sustain I carry about with me and never am a real sufferer except by my own fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Emerson's [*Essays: First Series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essays:_First_Series) (1841), he wrote this phrase but attributed it to [Saint Bernard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_of_Clairvaux) (not the dog):

> The gain is apparent; the tax is certain. But there is no tax on the knowledge that the compensation exists and that it is not desirable to dig up treasure. Herein I rejoice with a serene eternal peace. I contract the boundaries of possible mischief. I learn the wisdom of St. Bernard,--"Nothing can work me damage except myself; the harm that I sustain I carry about with me, and never am a real sufferer but by my own fault."
>
> <sub>-- Emerson ([source](http://www.literaturepage.com/read/emersonessays1-63.html))</sub>

I wasn't able to find out where St. Bernard said this. It's not in [his collected letters](https://ccel.org/ccel/b/bernard/letters/cache/letters.pdf), but it has been attributed to him [by others](https://www.bartleby.com/345/authors/38.html) as well as Emerson.

Comment: Thank you.  It has been bothering the hell out of me.  I have a copy of "Selected Writings of Ralph Waldo Emerson."  In that volume I know I read and first came across the quote.  However, I have no longer been able to find that quote.  When I first read the volume, I swear, it had the essay "Compensation".  The volume I now have (Signet Classics, The New American Library a division of Penguin Classics, © 1965 that I have now in possession does not have this essay.  The volume I purchased did.  What happened?  Thank you, once again, for answering my query and giving me a direction to proceed.